# Exponential of a matrix and related derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$
I have $ X \in M(n,\mathbb R) $ to be fixed. I define $ g(t) = \det(e^{tX}) $
Then the author proceeds as follows:
\begin{align}
g'(s) &= \frac {d}{dt} g(s+t)\\
&=\frac {d}{dt} \det(e^{(s+t)X}) |_{t=0}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}(\det(e^{sX})\det(e^{tX})|_{t=0}\\
&= g(s)\tr(X),
\end{align}
as $ s $ is independent of $ t $. The author proves this in the course of proving

$$ \det(\exp(X))=\exp(\tr(X)) $$

My question is why is the function $ g $ concocted for this proof? Also how is the very first step understood? I apologise if I am missing something quite simple and thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: The first and last steps are not clear to me...in particular, if he wants to prove the euqation with the determinant, why to use it in the last equality ? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Well the first step is not clear to me either. As for the last step which I think sort of answers my first question is that $ tr(X) = \frac{d}{dt} det(e^{tX}) |_{t=0} $

Comment: I think that a cleaner notation is the following: $g: (s,t)\mapsto g(s,t):=det(exp(s+t)X)$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(s,0)=...$

Comment: Btw, to prove the $det(exp(X))=exp(tr(X))$ equation I would decompose $X$ w.r.t. upper triangular decomposition: it is a quite common trick.

Comment: check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418067/exponential-matrix/418211#418211 if you are interested. I hope it helps

Comment: I am aware of the other way of proving the said thing. I just wanted to understand this proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\exp}{exp}\DeclareMathOperator{\det}{det}\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$Here's my take on unpacking your source's argument. Observe that
$$
 \exp(\tr(tX)) = e^{\tr(X)t}, \quad t \in \mathbb{R},
$$
so that if the function $g(t) := \det(\exp(tX))$ satisfies the initial value problem
$$
 g^\prime(t) = \tr(X)g(t), \quad g(0) = 1,
$$
then by the basic theory of ODE,
$$
 \det(\exp(tX)) =: g(t) = g(0)e^{\tr(X) t} = \exp(\tr(tX)), \quad t \in \mathbb{R},
$$
yielding the desired result. So, your source's strategy is precisely to check that $g(t)$ does indeed satisfy the relevant initial value problem; since $g(0) = 1$ by a simple calculation, it suffices to check that $g^\prime(t) = \tr(X)g(t)$.

Now, fix $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $0 \neq h \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
 g(t+h) = \det(\exp((t+h)X)) = \det(\exp(tX)\exp(hX)) = g(t)g(h),
$$
so that
$$
 \frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h} = \frac{g(h)-1}{h}g(t).
$$
Hence, to conclude that
$$
 g^\prime(t) := \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h} = \tr(X)g(t),
$$
it suffices to check that
$$
 g^\prime(0) := \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)-1}{h} = \tr(X),
$$
but this in turn can be easily checked on upper triangular matrices. Perhaps you could also use [this answer by Avitus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418067/exponential-matrix/%E2%80%A6) together with the chain rule, though using the Jacobi formula for the total derivative of the determinant might be tricky in its own right.

Comment: (+1): the trick $exp( trX t)=e^{ trX t}$ and the subsequent ODE analysis are nice!

Comment: I am unable to use Avitus' answer with the chain rule and get the answer.Please help! I want to avoid using the other method you mentioned. Plus I am still not convinced about the appearance of "s+t" in my original question.

Comment: So the strategy is exactly one and the same: check that $g^\prime(s) = \operatorname{tr}(X)g(s)$. That said, your source actually assumes the differentiability of $g$ (which is OK, if you know that $t \mapsto e^{t X}$ is differentiable, by Avitus's answer), and also assumes without any comment the critical fact that $g^\prime(0) = \operatorname{tr}(X)$. As for the $s+t$ business, your source is using the fact that for a function $f$ of a real variable $s$, $f^\prime(s) = \tfrac{d}{dt}f(s+t)|_{t=0}$, which is a straightforward exercise in basic calculus.

Comment: If you want to prove that $g^\prime(0) = \operatorname{tr}(X)$, which your source, going by what you wrote out here, takes for granted, then the easiest way is to prove it for upper triangular matrices, which is easy and straightforward, and then exploit the similarity invariance of the determinant and trace. Now that it isn't late at night and I've taken another look, using, say, Jacobi's formula for the differential of the determinant function together with the chain rule probably isn't worth the bother.

Comment: I think I have got the first step. It merely seems to be saying that: $ \frac{d}{dt}g(t) |_{t=s} = \frac{d}{dt}g(s+t) |_{t=0} $

Comment: Yeah, I am changing my mind. Maybe checking out the upper triangular matrices as you suggested is the better option. Will do that and hope my previous observation is right.Oops, didnt read your first comment where you had already said the same thing I just said. Sorry

Comment: Yes it does, though quite a few pages before using the function $ f(A) = det(A) $ and taking the curve $ \gamma(t) = e^{tX} $ where $   \gamma(0)=I , \gamma '(t)=X $ and then by taking the directional derivative of f along $ \gamma $